# substring in AWS CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I get the account ID in CloudFormation as `"AWS::AccountId"`, it gives output say `"52514856415"`.

How to get the last four characters i.e. `"6415"`?

I like to append these last 4 chars to S3 bucket name.

Comment: How did it go? Still confused about the substrings?

Comment: Thanks for asking. Was not successful to get it running. For my use-case full string was also an option and overhead of "macros" was not desired.

Comment: As explained in my answers, you can't do this using CF without macros. Maybe have a look at terraform?

Answer (score 2):

Sadly, you **can't do this**. There is no such operation in CloudFormation. You would have to create [macro](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-cloudformation-macro.html) for that. Examples of string macros are [here](https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/aws-cloudformation-macros/tree/master/StringFunctions).